# AND condition followed by OR between BETWEEN in CakePHP 3.4x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

**What I am trying to get:**

```sql
SELECT col,col,col FROM x WHERE id = :c0 AND ((colx BETWEEN :c1 AND :c2) OR (colx BETWEEN :c3 AND :c4))
```

**What I tried:**

```php
$finalList = $finalList->find()->where(['id' => $id]);
foreach($dataArray as $y):
$finalList = $finalList->orWhere(function($expressions) use ($y['min'], $y['max']) {
    return $expressions->between('colx', $y['min'], $y['max']);
}
endforeach;
```

**What I am getting:**

```sql
SELECT col,col,col FROM x WHERE id = :c0 OR colx BETWEEN :c1 AND :c2 OR colx BETWEEN :c3 AND :c4
```

I want id to be *required* and OR between BETWEEN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how `orWhere()` works. Quote from the API docs:

> It is important to notice that when calling this function, any previous set
>   of conditions defined for this query will be treated as a single argument for
>   the OR operator. This function will not only operate the most recently defined
>   condition, but all the conditions as a whole.

It's not overly straight forward though, which is why [**`orWhere()` has recently been deprecated**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10845).

To get this working using `orWhere()`, you'd have to apply the `where()` (or `andWhere()`) after `orWhere()`, ie:

```
$finalList = $finalList->find();
foreach($dataArray as $y) {
    // ... apply orWhere()
}
$finalList->where(['id' => $id]);
```

Alternatively use the expression builder all the way through:

```
$finalList = $finalList->where(function ($exp) use ($dataArray) {
    $or = $exp->or_([]);
    foreach($dataArray as $y) {
        $or->between('colx', $y['min'], $y['max']);
    }

    return $exp->add(['id' => 1, $or]);
});
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::orWhere()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_orWhere)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression::or_](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Expression.QueryExpression.html#_or_)**

Comment: Curious though. It somehow isn't working as anticipated. Tried adding AND where at the end but no go. I guess extending ExpressionBuilder could be a possibility. Hmm... Tricky.

Comment: Oh! I was returning $or direction from `foreach`. Thank you @ndm. The later solved the problem.